# c# 3DConnexion (Wireless) catch ButtonLeft and ButtonRight event

Tags: c#, 3d, mouseevent

i use a 3d mouse from 3dconnexion.

i want that i can use the mouse in my project:
moving a 3d model and rotate it.
also i want to use the buttons (right and left) for the application.

i have already find out that the wndproc msg for the BOTH Buttons is 675. 
But i cannot differe them.

but the library is a little bit "underpowerd" (my opinion)

Does anyone can help me or give me a hint?
am i stupid or is it not that easy?

(sry for my bad english :/)

Finki

Comment: "the library is underpowered"...reading that, I'm wondering what library you are talking about? the official 3dconnexion-sdk is everything but underpowered. it even includes samples for using the native-driver in c# where you actually have seperated events for your buttons

Comment: okay...i use the _3DconnexionLibrary but i found nothing to catch the button-event and also no way to trigger the calibration. Could u help me?